# Strange response from program

Tags: c, double, assert

Okay i have written up a code that converts a string to a decimal

however i am not understanding why it is core dumping on the second assert when the first one works fine

if i print out the return from the function it is actually returning what it is supposed to be returning but for some reason the assert fails

so can somebody help me understand what is going on with assert here? i dont understand why it is failing?

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

double myAtoD(char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *k="0.1";
    char *l="0.141";
    double m,n;

   m = myAtoD(k);
   n = myAtoD(l);

   printf("%f\n",m);
   assert(m==0.1);

   printf("%f\n",n);
   assert(n==0.141);    

    return 0;
}

double myAtoD (char *message){

   int i=0;
   int prior=0;
   double num=0;

   while(message[i]!='.'){
      prior++;
      i++;
   }

   i=0;

   prior--;

   while(message[i]!='\0'){

      if(message[i]=='.')
      i++;

      printf("num is %f\nnew number to be added is %f\n\n",num, (message[i] - '0')*pow(10,prior));  
      num += (message[i] - '0')*pow(10,prior); 
      i++;
      prior--;
   }

   return num;
}
```

Comment: Obligatory cross-reference: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  It covers the issues you're suffering from.  You might eventually get interested in [General Decimal Arithmetic](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/).

Comment: the function myAtoD() fails to check that the char being read from message is numeric (in range of 030h ... 039h for ascii characters) and returning the value generated so far.

Answer (score 3):

You dealing with `double` precision issues.

The number `0.141` cannot be represented exactly by the computer, so you will have to instead check whether it is a small `epsilon` away from `0.141` instead.

Here is a better assertion.

```
   assert(abs(n-0.141) < DBL_EPSILON);
```

For that constant, you will need to put `#include <float.h>` at the top of your source file.

Comment: Suggest `DBL_EPSILON` from `<float.h>` instead of `1E-9` and `fabs(n)` rather than `abs(n)`.

Comment: whats the n represent in that? `assert(abs(n-0.141)<1E-9)`

Comment: @yukapuka, Your source code. It is the `n` from your source code.

Comment: how do i make my function work so that it gives exactly what assert is asking for?

Comment: @yukapuka, I am not sure I understand your question, but if you replace your current assert with the one that I wrote in the answer, it should make the assert work.

Comment: so from what i have understood the reason my assert is failing is because even though if i print my response it will show 0.141 the reality is that the number being stored could be something like 0.141000007 hence why the assert is failing 

so in order to get assert not to fail i need to truncate that extra number somewhere to clean up the double to be precise ?

Comment: @yukapuka, Assert is failing because the number stored is not exactly `0.141`. **Correct**. Need to truncate the extra number. **Incorrect**.

Comment: @yukapuka, Unless you are using arbitrary precision types, you will have to live with the fact that a `double` in `C` lacks enough precision to represent `0.141` exactly. That means that when you do `assert` to check whether a `double` is equal to `0.141`, you have to check whether it is *sufficiently close*, instead of checking for equality.

Answer (score 1):

A candidate improvement to `myAtoD()` that is more computationally stable.  Although it provides a nice answer for "0.141", it may nor be the best for all input - need to do more testing.  But @merlin2011 suggestion to allow a little wiggle room is good.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

double myAtoD (const char *message){
  double num = 0.0;
  int dp = '.';
  size_t dpi;
  size_t i = 0;
  for (i=0; message[i]; i++) {
    int ch = (unsigned char) message[i];
    if (ch == dp) {
      dp = '\0';
      dpi = i;
      continue;
    }
    if (isdigit(ch)) {
      num = num*10 + (ch - '0');
    }
    else {
      break; // illegal character
    }
  }
  if (dp == '\0') {
    num /= pow10(i - dpi - 1);
  }
  return num;
}
```

[Edit]

A *very* precise and robust conversion of text to a `double` is non-trivial - best to do with some sort of extended precision. The above simple routine is certain to provide an answer within 2 [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).